# HTTP 500 error when I require PHP facebook SDK at Symfony2

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, symfony-2.1

I've added requirement

```
require_once __DIR__ . './facebook/src/facebook.php';
```

at vendor/autoload.php file.
And all is OK while I'm working on localhost using [denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/).
But when I try to use this on real server, I get HTTP 500 Error. Why?

Comment: Look into your server’s error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the CURL has not been installed.